# using page access tokenAllow users to post on my facebook page

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I am using facebook php sdk4 to post on my page wall. I'm able to post on my page wall using my account using following steps:

1. Login with facebook
2. Get my user access token
3. Request for page access token and post something on page wall

This works fine if i'm logged in as admin

but if i login as normal user. I cannot get access token. I'm trying to make a php page that contains a form.And when i submit that form after logging in on facebook. It should post the message on my PAGE WALL(not user wall). Is it possible to allow post on my PAGE WALL from normal user using SDK. I tried posting as normal user on my page wall using facebook it works fine.. Can i do this using SDK?

Comment: why would you want every user to post "as page"?

Comment: @luschn I have tried posting without page token. When i open page as normal user .The page is showing my recent posts. But when i log in as page admin, nothings there not even in unpublished section

Comment: ok, now i have no clue what you want to achieve